# Matrix element of $\sin{\phi/2}$ within the harmonic approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, harmonic-oscillator

I'm reading [Bogoliubov Quasiparticles in Superconducting Qubits](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.04366) by Glazman and Catelani and I'm stuck of one of their derivations. It's a long review article about many things not related to the question, so let's just zoom in on that part.

My problem is with how one obtains equation 75:
\begin{equation}
\vert\langle 0 \vert \sin \frac{\phi}{2}\vert 1 \rangle\vert^2 = \frac{E_C}{\hbar \omega_{10}} \frac{1+ \cos\phi_0}{2}
\end{equation}
where $\omega_{10}=\sqrt{8E_C\left(E_L+E_J\cos{\phi_0}\right)}/\hbar$ and charging energy $E_C$, Josephson energy $E_J$, and inductive energy $E_L$, which are parameters relating to superconducting qubits but should not be essential for the question.

Reading the lines above, they have the Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
4 E_C N^2 + \frac{1}{2}\left(E_L + E_J\cos\phi_0\right) (\phi-\phi_0)^2
\end{equation}
They then simply state that it is straightforward to calculate the matrix element by expanding the sin to linear order around $\phi_0$, obtaining the result stated above.

Now I agree that this is just a harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian. But what am I missing that makes this evaluation so straightforward? Which identities from harmonic oscillators am I failing to recall? If someone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After expanding the sin term this is derived by evaluating the matrix elements of the position operator between eigenstates $|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$ of the harmonic oscillator.

The solution is given in this paper ([Relaxation and frequency shifts induced by quasiparticles in superconducting qubits](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.0829)) at equation 53.